# Formatação/Quebra de linha de código no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Quando faço a reformatação automática <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> o código fica identado, porém as linhas não quebram, como acontece no Eclipse e no Netbeans, de modo que eu tenho ficar arrastando a janela constantemente para ver o final de uma linha maior, como no exemplo:

```
NtpTimeProvider ntpTimeProvider = new NtpTimeProvider(InetAddressFactory.newFromHostString("192.168.0.1"), nodeMainExecutor.getScheduledExecutorService());
```

Alguém saberia onde eu posso configurar isso para que as linhas quebrem e o código fique do tamanho da janela?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa ir em Files > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > wrapping and Braces > Marcar a opção: Ensure right margins is not exceeded

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]